# Android Security-Protection Levels for a permission-systemOrsignature

Tags: android, security, permissions

Can anyone please clarify on the Protection Levels for a permission?
Below is my understanding:

"Protection levels - ‘signature’ and ‘systemOrsignature’ are same except for the below reason. In either case a system app is always having the permission.

Suppose X is defining permission with Protection level systemOrsignature.

And Y is a system app that is part of the system image,
then Y has the permission.

And if Z is another vendor app that has a same certificate/signature (if the developer (OEM) of X has shared it with vendor),
then Z too has the permission, even if Z is not part of system image.

So, this helps non-system apps that share OEM signature. "

Also, Is there a way to prevent the system apps that dont have a permission in its Manifest from the access.
To be clear:
"Suppose X is defining permission with Protection level systemOrsignature.
And Y is a system app that is part of the system image,
then Y has the permission. "

In this case is it possible to prevent Y from having the permission?

Please clarify.